# How does the sudo key symbol work?

Tags: macos, terminal, password, sudo

I'm trying to write a script that requests the user password for some `sudo`-related commands. My goal is to emulate the default method that OS X uses to obtain the user's password, `Password:` followed by a key-like symbol, as seen in the screenshot attached below:

[image: key symbol]

I tried the answer from [How to get a password from a shell script without echoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980668/how-to-get-a-password-from-a-shell-script-without-echoing) over on Stack Overflow that uses `read -s`, but that results in `Password:` without the key symbol **when run from a script**, but displays the symbol when run from the Terminal itself . What is this key symbol, and can I find it under the Characters menu?

Comment: I get the key symbol when running `read -s` in Terminal, so I assume this is actually a feature of bash. Maybe a look into the source code (http://opensource.apple.com/source/bash/bash-99/bash-3.2/builtins/read.c) might give more clues.

Comment: @patrix I see, now I understand. I did not have `read -s` set up correctly in my script. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @patrix Kindly do add an answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Check. And it's probably a feature of Terminal even.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the key symbol when running `read -s` in Terminal.

As this seems to work the same for `read -s` as for `sudo`, I assume this is a feature of Terminal (to display a key symbol whenever input is requested in silent/hidden mode).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is just write the script without sudo

then tell the user to run it with sudo e.g. `sudo script`

the script will run with root privileges

`this has the advantage that the user knows what asks for and where the password is used, if in your script you could be taking a copy or leaving it in memory

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. While I understand that you can run a script in its entirety as a root user, I would like to emulate the password-obtaining mechanism of `sudo`. I apologise if I was unclear.

Comment: You were clear but I think it is a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with whether the terminal echo option is disabled. I tried running `stty -echo; cat; stty echo` in my terminal and then typing something, and the key symbol showed. I then pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and it went away.